# properties file not loading in Unix machine but the same is working on windows machine. could not understand why?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.3.6 and tomcat 7 for our web application. I have the following configuration in my xml file :-

```
<bean id="appResourcesProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:resources\xxxxxxResources.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This worked fine on windows machine but when the same deployed on unix machine the properties file did not get loaded.

Then i have removed "*" after the classpath and modified as below:-

```
<bean id="appResourcesProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:resources\WCApplicationResources.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This worked fine on unix machine. Why this happened? I could not understand the reason. Can somebody help me understand this. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is '\', try using '/' instead, like `resources/WCApplicationResources.properties`

Comment: if '\' is the reason then why is it working when i just removed '*' without any other changes?  According to your explanation it should not work until i change '\' to '/'.

Answer (score 1):

> Classpath*: portability
>
> The wildcard classpath relies on the getResources() method of the
>   underlying classloader....
>   In case an inappropriate result is returned, check the application server documentation for settings that might affect the classloader behavior.

And the getResources finds like this:

```
The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource.
```

Hope it helps in something.